# Mobile to mobile communication without mobile tower?

Tags: android, mesh-network

Is it possible to somehow manipulate mobile device antenna to connect other mobile device directly.Does android API provide any such functions ?
Anyone know any related implementation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow manipulate mobile device antenna to connect other mobile device directly.

Not with ordinary hardware. If you can find an Android-powered device offering software-defined radio (SDR), then maybe.

> Does android API provide any such functions ?

No.